# Pass functional component from child to parent in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, modal-dialog

Is it possible to pass a functional component from a child component to a parent component? I'm trying to do a dynamic modal that is displayed inside the parent but that the children can populate through a function from a provider, for example:

```
setModal(() => (
    <div>content</div>)
)
```

And the parent receives this component:

```
const [modal, setModal] = useState(false)
const [modalContent, setModalContent] = useState<FunctionComponent>()
...
<Provider value={{
    setModal: (content: FunctionComponent) => {
        setModalContent(content); // This updates the state to hold a function component and to re-render
        setModal(true); // This updates a state flag to show the overlay in which the modal is rendered
    },
}}>
...
</Provider>
```

The content of the modal should be dynamic. I was trying to use the state of the component to hold the functional component but I don't think if that's possible or if it's a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're still looking to pass a function from the parent to each child but each child should be able to change the state of a modal component that the parent also has ownership over.

For the above scenario this is something you can do:

```js
const Provider = ({ children, updateModal }) => {
  // With this, every child has the ability to call updateModal
  return React.Children(children).map(child => cloneElement(child, { updateModal }));
};

const ModalComponent = ({ open, children }) => {
  if (!open) return null;

  return (
    <dialog>
      {children}
    </dialog>
  );
};

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const [modalContent, setModalContent] = useState(null);

  const updateModal = (content) => {
    setModalContent(content);
    setModal(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Provider updateModal={updateModal}>
        {...insert children here}
      </Provider>
      <ModalComponent open={modal}>
        {modalContent}
      </ModalComponent>
    </>

  );
};
```